# MySQL Join on 2 tables based on text field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables: `"list"` and `"more"`

> The "list" table has upwards of 100,000 results.
>
> The "more" table has upwards of 50,000 results.

The data from these tables cannot be combined.

The issue is, I have a column called "short_title" in both tables. They are both VARCHAR(255) and will contain a string like "short-title-here".

I'm using a simple query like:

```
SELECT L.title, M.more_info
FROM `list` L, `more` M
WHERE M.short_title = L.short_title
```

Since there are so many results in each table, and I need to be matching the results based on the "short_title" column which is a text field, it makes the queries EXTREMELY slow.

There is an INDEX on the `"short_title"` column in the `"list"` table, and the `"short_title"` column in my `"more"` table is UNIQUE

Is there anything I can do to the column (example: making them fulltext) that will make these queries faster?

Thank you in advance

**** UPDATE ****

I've changed my query to INNER JOIN the two tables.

The results of the explain query can be found here:

[image: Results of the Explain Query]

Comment: since you are comparing the columns for equality, I don't think you need fulltext capabilities... just be sure to have an index on the short_title column of both tables.

Comment: Thank you, but my `"short_title"` column in the `"list"` table already contains an INDEX, and the `"short_title"` column in my `"more"` table is set to UNIQUE -- If I add an index on it, phpMyAdmin alerts me that I shouldn't have two INDEXes on the same column

Comment: Are you sure index statistics are updated? If not the engine might not be able to use your indexes correctly. How long does the query execution take? Do you have an explain plan to show us? Just to check the index is being used. Also... have you tried the INNER JOIN syntax instead of the old multitable WHERE syntax?

Comment: As for the index statistics, I'm not entirely sure -- is there a way of checking or re-indexing them to make sure they're up to date? The query appears to take roughly 2 seconds to execute once I changed it to an INNER JOIN. I'll take a photo of the EXPLAIN and upload it here momentarily.

Comment: I've added the results of the EXPLAIN query

Comment: Excuse me... are you sure that is the explain of the exact query you showed us? Using temporary and using filesort... that looks a lot like an ORDER BY or some other condition you have not told us about. And why is key_len 767 for the list table? Didn't you say the columns envolved are VARCHAR(255)?

Comment: The original query I showed you was a shortened version of the actual query, but accurately describes the issue.

I have 2 other WHERE clauses but the crux of this issue lies in the short_title column. There is also an ORDER BY at the end, but like I just said, the problem lies in short_title columns from the tables `list` and `more` being matched

Comment: When you pose optimization issues... you have to show the exact query you are running. This explain plan does not seem to match your simple query. There are still many missing details, without which it is almost impossible to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try indexing the short_title fields.

Comment: The "short_title" columns are indexed already. In my "list" table, they are an INDEX, and in my "more" table, they are UNIQUE

Answer (score 0):

This is your query (written using explicit joins):

```
SELECT L.title, M.more_info
FROM list L join
     more M 
     on M.short_title = L.short_title;
```

You state that `short_title` is being stored as `text`.  You can create a regular index on it by doing:

```
create index more_short_title on more(short_title(255));
```

The `255` is the number of bytes to be indexed.  This should speed up the queries.

Also, with a name like `short_title`, why not just use a `varchar()` column rather than `text`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I should have clarified a bit more.

My "short_title" columns are text fields in the sense that they contain text. They are in reality VARCHAR(255)

Comment: @user1298740 . . . Then just build the index without the `255` length option.

Comment: @user1298740 . . . Put "explain" before your query and edit your question with the results.